# Avro schema evolution - convert primitive field to complex one

Tags: avro

Could you please tell me, if it's possible or not to implement such kind of schema evolution in Avro? So, V1 message could be converted into V2 automatically.

V1:

```
{ "title": "Some title" }
```

convert to V2:

```
{ "title": [ { "value": "Some title", "type": "main" } ] }
```

Assuming that old "title" field should be treated as "main" title in the new schema.

Or alternative option of V2:

```
{ "title": { "main": "Some title" } }
```

So, old value is transformed into map with "main" key.

Is it possible to do just by using Avro schema capabilities?

Comment: You tell us. What kinds of errors do you get when you try to read this "new format"?

Comment: I am just asking about Avro schema evolving capabilities. Seems like what I am asking for is not possible with Avro

Comment: I don't think you can convert string types into non nullable records/maps, no. But if you make the title field a nullable union type to begin with, it should be possible. Like I said, what kinds of errors do you get when you try?